# Trying to call a jquery function with no event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So turning and image into a link like this

```
var imgCell = '<a href="javascript:storeInfo(&quot;text&quot;,&quot;text&quot;,&quot;ActiveProjects&quot;);"><img src="https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_open.png"></a>';
```

This calls the storeInfo function which will take the "text" "text" and "activeprojects and set them to global variables so they can be used by multiple javascript functions...

```
function storeInfo (filePath, webAddress, projectStatus){
theFilePath = filePath;
theWebAddress = webAddress;
controlButton(projectStatus);}
```

Then within the storeInfo function I call this function...

```
function controlButton (projectStatus){
$('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img').live('click', function () {
    var theTable = ActiveProjectsTable;

    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
        {
            // This row is already open - close it 
            this.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_open.png";
            theTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
    else
        {
            // Open this row 
            this.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_close.png";
            theTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(theTable, nTr), 'details' );
        }
});
}
```

So one the first click of the img it calls the store info function which in return calls the controlButton function... Then within the control button function there is the jquery code function which requires another click... I want to know if there is a way to call the jquery function with no event so that I dont need 2 clicks.

How can I just call the jquery function once controlButton is called?

Comment: your `live` is inside the fucntion `controlbutton` This will install an eventhandler only when you click the link 1st time. Then it needs a second click to  execute the code inside the `click` handler installed with the 'live' instruction

Answer (score 1):

```
function controlButton (projectStatus){
    // save the function into a variable
    var funct = function () {
        var theTable = ActiveProjectsTable;

        var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
        {
            // This row is already open - close it 
            this.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_open.png";
            theTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
            // Open this row 
            this.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_close.png";
            theTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(theTable, nTr), 'details' );
        }
    }
    // Retrieve the DOM node
    var node = $('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img');

    // Apply the event listener to the node
    node.live('click', funct);

    // Call the function, with the retrieved node as the call instance('this')
    funct.call(node);
}
```

Comment: I still have to double click to call the "theTable.fnOpen" and close functions I'm looking for a way to call open and close the cell of the table in one click

Comment: We'd need to see a larger sample of the code my friend. Also, I ended up editing it a bit from my inital post do to a small error.

Comment: I added in the store info function and I dont think it will work because the code requires a click inside the controlButton function and that is already being hit from a click... Im trying to call this without having to click again.